# xmltype weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, grails, oracle11g, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to deploy a Grails application in weblogic 10.3.6.
Grails version is 2.5.0 and java jdk1.7.0_79.

It works fine with jdk1.7.0_79 and grails 2.3.7.

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean prope
ty 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested excepti
n is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I add xdb6.jar at the modules/lib..it doesn't pick that jar and still complains.

Any thoughts?